# Kubernetes livenessProbe: restarting vs destroying of the pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to tell Kubernetes to just destroy a pod and create a new one if the liveness probe fails? What I see from logs now: my node js application is just restarted and runs in the same pod.

The liveness probe is defined in my YAML specification as follows:

```
livenessProbe:
 httpGet:
 path: /app/check/status
 port: 3000
 httpHeaders:
 - name: Accept
   value: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 initialDelaySeconds: 60
 periodSeconds: 60
```

Disclaimer:

I am fully aware that recreating a pod if a liveness prove fails is probably not the best idea and a right way would be to get a notification that something is going on.

Comment: So is setting the [restart policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy) to `Never` not an option?

Answer (score 6):

So liveness and readiness probes are defined in [containers not pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) so if you have 1 container in your pod and you specify `restartPolicy` to `Never`. Then your pod will go into a `Failed` state and will be scrapped at some point based on the `terminated-pod-gc-threshold` value.

If you have more than one container in your pod it becomes tricker because of your other container(s) running making the pod still be in `Running` status.  You can build your own automation or try [Pod Readiness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-readiness-gate) which is still in alpha as of this writing.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it does not tear down the pod. Still only restarts the container. `restartPolicy: Never` gives me an error when I put it in the spec: `spec.template.spec.restartPolicy: Unsupported value: "Never": supported values: "Always"`. Ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you are using a Deployment that only [allows](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy) Always as the pod restart policy